# What is the number of concurrent users support for Nodejs?

Tags: performance, node.js

i need to scale my system to handle at least 500k users. I came across nodejs and it's quite intriguing.

Do anyone have any idea of how many concurrent users it can support? Has anyone really tested it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you expect all this users to have persistent tcp connections to your server concurrently?

The bottleneck is probably memory with V8 [1gb limit](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=847) (1.7 on 64bit)

You can try to load test with several hundreds to few thousands connections, log heap usage and extrapolate to find one node instance connections limit.

Comment: Also while keeping in mind that Node is single threaded and that if a function is really slow in returning everyone will be held up.  Node happens to shine because most of the time the cpu is waiting on io.

Comment: @Andrey: Yes i want to keep the connection alive.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, but hard to answer. I think the amount of concurrent users is dependent on the amount of processing done with each request and the hardware you are using, eg. amount of memory and processor speed. If you want to use multiple cores, you could use multi-node. Multi-node will start multiple node instances. I never used it, but it looks promising.

You could do a quick test using ab, part of apache.
500k concurrent users is quite a lot, and would make me consider using multiple servers and a load-balancer.

Just my 2ct. Hope this helps.